# How to unpack and use fixed length records from compressed (xz) binary files?

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce, unpack

I want to read an xz compressed binary file with fixed-length records and unpack it's contents. I used hadoop-xz for xz codec. The exception says there is no support for reading compresed binary files. Is there any workaround for it?

This is the code that I tried.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from struct import unpack
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("io.compression.codecs","io.sensesecure.hadoop.xz.XZCodec")
trace_format='<Q2B2B4B2Q4Q'
file=sc.binaryRecords('test.xz',64)
file.flatMap(lambda line: unpack(trace_format,line)[0]).collect()
```

This is the exception that I got.

```
23/03/21 14:19:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.io.IOException: FixedLengthRecordReader does not support reading compressed files
    at org.apache.spark.input.FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.initialize(FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(NewHadoopRDD.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
23/03/21 14:19:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (10.110.30.68 executor driver): java.io.IOException: FixedLengthRecordReader does not support reading compressed files
    at org.apache.spark.input.FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.initialize(FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(NewHadoopRDD.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

23/03/21 14:19:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```